# Image asset path from Core Data into PNG

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, core-data, uiimageview

I'm storing the file location in the asset library of photos taken using the camera in my core data graph to avoid having a huge database and memory problems.

For example:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=2F62642E-00B3-4D85-82D2-A6A1F064F2CE&ext=JPG
```

I'm now creating a pdf file that displays these images in a nice table, however I have no idea how to convert the asset path to a usable UIImage and represent it as a PNG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `ALAssetsLibrary` to retrieve the corresponding asset, with the `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:` method. This will return either the `ALAsset` object (which you can then use to obtain an image), or an error.

It's very important that you handle the errors gracefully, because the asset URLs can and do change: either through user actions (e.g, the user has deleted the asset and it's no longer available) or through something else (iOS updates can invalidate asset URLs).